# Show last date in multiple join with multiple data

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a SQL code where I join 3 tables.

SQL:

```
SELECT c.number AS id_number, concat(p.name, ' ', p.surname) AS owner, b.beigu_term as insurance_term
FROM car AS c
JOIN personas as p ON c.fk_owner = p.pk_kods
JOIN insurance_operator as b ON b.car_id = c.pk_kods
```

The SQL output

```
+------------+-------------+----------------+
| id_number  | owner       | insurance_term |
+------------+-------------+----------------+
| AA0001     | Anna Johns  | 2006-01-01     |       
| AA0002     | John Wilk   | 2006-01-01     | 
| AA0003     | John Boot   | 2006-02-01     |
| AA0001     | Anna Johns  | 2007-01-01     |
| AA0002     | John Wilk   | 2005-01-01     |       
| AA0006     | Anna Johns  | 2007-01-01     |       
| AA0007     | John Wilk   | 2005-01-01     |       
+------------+-------------+----------------+
```

One owner can have multiple cars, but my SQL need's to show the last insurance term, as you can see in SQL output car with id AA0001 is printed two times, but this car should be printed 1 time with the last insurance date what is 2007-01-01.
How can I do this ?

Comment: Please edit the question to show the desired result in tabular form, and can the id_number be associated with two (or more) different owners?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this, you should use the group by functionality in combination with max (for determining the maximum date).

```
SELECT c.number AS id_number, concat(p.name, ' ', p.surname) AS owner, max(b.beigu_term) as insurance_term
FROM car AS c
JOIN personas as p ON c.fk_owner = p.pk_kods
JOIN insurance_operator as b ON b.car_id = c.pk_kods
GROUP BY c.number, concat(p.name, ' ', p.surname)
```

Comment: This seems to be it.  I don't know why someone put -1 for this. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> One owner can have multiple cars, but my SQL need's to show the last insurance term,

This suggests window functions:

```
SELECT id_number, owner, insurance_term
FROM (SELECT c.number AS id_number, concat(p.name, ' ', p.surname) AS owner, io.beigu_term as insurance_term,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c.number ORDER BY io.beigu_term DESC) as seqnum
      FROM car c JOIN
           personas p
           ON c.fk_owner = p.pk_kods JOIN
           insurance_operator io
           ON io.car_id = c.pk_kods
     ) cp
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

Note:  If there are duplicate insurance terms with the same time frame and you want all of them, then use `RANK()`instead of `ROW_NUMBER()`.